# UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell touch detect

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview with 8 custom cells. in the 8th cell I added a scrollView with paging enabled so I can show page 1 and page 2 (or 3, 4... 10) without have a very high cell.

The problem is with the scrollView I can't use didSelectRowAtIndexPath because the cell is behind the scrollView so I'm trying to detect scrollView tap (not swipe).

I played with touchesBegan and touchesEnded but they are never called (I know touches work with UIView only, but maybe.....)

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the simplest solution for my needs:

subclass UIScrollView touchesEnded method and post a notification.

In the UITableview add an observer in viewdidAppear (remove it in viewdiddisappear) to call a function that call tableview didSelectRowForIndexPath.

Something like this (swift version)

```
// myScrollView.swift

import UIKit

class myScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("selectTVRow", object: nil)
    }
}
```

In your tableView:

```
// ItemsList.swift

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "selectFourthRow", name: "selectTVRow", object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "selectfourthrow", object: nil)
    }

    func selectFourthRow() {
        let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0);
        self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect);
    }

    /*
    .... rest of your tableview Datasource and Delegate methods...
    numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath
    */
```

Answer (score 97):

There is a trick Apple recommends to use in this case, in theirs [WWDC 2014 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) "Advanced scrollviews" (See Demo starting from 8:10):

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:_scrollView];
[_scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:_scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

That's all what needs to be done, no need to override `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:` and others.

---

I used solution based on overriding of `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:` previously, but sometimes it caused a weird behaviour: when select a certain cell, method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` was called for cell with different indexPath.

Solution from Apple has no side effects so far and looks more elegant.

Comment: Only downside to this solution was that it disabled interaction on any `UIButton`s inside the scroll view. I resorted back to using `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:` myself.

Comment: This solution provides the same selection characteristics of a normal tableview cell, so it's the best as long as none of the content in the scrollview needs to have user interaction enabled.

Comment: Stumbled upon this and figured I would mention: In order for this to work, make sure you are adding any and all subviews to cell.contentView

Comment: @petehare can you explain in little bit details what you have done to solve `UIButton` event issue? I know it's old conversation but it will be helpful

Comment: I can't find the WWDC session, does anyone know how to access it?

Answer (score 17):

There is also an elegant resolution:

Create a SubClass from UIScrollView and override the following methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self superview]touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self superview]touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self superview]touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self superview]touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Passing every touch to the superview of the scroll view and then the didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be called.

Comment: This is  by far the best and most elegant solution for this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder how would this work if I also have buttons in the cell ?

Comment: The problem is that touches of the ScrollView will not be passed to its parent view, so the solution is to pass every touch in all touch phase to its parent view. You don't need worry about the button, it receives the touch event first.

Comment: I had a button behind the scrollview and it didn't receive touches... Ofc the solution was to put the button inside of the scrollview

Comment: If you don't want to put the button inside the scroll view, the solution will be more complicated, you can detect whether the touch is inside the button area, if so, pass the touches to the button rather than the superview

Answer (score 5):

Solved subclassing both uitableviewcell and uiscrollview.

It worked for my needs. Hope it can help.

Max

---

myScrollView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myScrollView : UIScrollView {
}

@end
```

myScrollView.m

```
#import "myScrollView.h"
@implementation myScrollView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{   
    NSLog(@"touch scroll");
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging) 
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded: touches withEvent:event]; 
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

myCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface myCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@end
```

myCell.m

```
#import "myCell.h"


@implementation myCell


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event 
{   
    NSLog(@"touch cell");
    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class myCell;
@class myScrollView;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

    myCell *cell;
    myScrollView *scrollView;
}

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // my custom cell
    cell = [[myCell alloc] init];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[myCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    // the custom scroll view
    scrollView = [[myScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 40);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];

    //something to add in scrollView
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 20)];
    label.text = @"some text";
    [scrollView addSubview:label];

    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer is correct, but I updated the code based on a bug I was getting.

In the subclassed scroll view add the following code.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.dragging) {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    } else {
        if ([self.delegate isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            [(UITableViewCell *)self.delegate touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
        }

        [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

If your `self.delegate` is not the `UITableViewCell`, than replace that property with a property to your cell.

The cell needs to retrieve the cancel touch event during movement to prevent the undesired results. It can be easily reproducible as follows.

- Highlight the cell (assuming the scroll view is over the whole cell, if not highlight the scroll view)
- While the cell is highlighted, drag the table view
- Select any other cell and now the previously highlighted cell will retrieve the `didSelectCell` state

Another point to mention is that order matters! If the `self.delegate` is not called before the `self.superview` then the highlighted state wont happen.

Comment: Thanks. I never faced that bug because my cell cannot be selected. I tap it and present a new view, so I cannot move table while cell is selected/highlighted. Thanks, Max