# Touch events of Scrollview in subview of UITableviewCell in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have tried searching over the internet about this problem but not able to come up with the solution that solves my problem.

I have make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` in which I added `UIScrollView` as a subview, now I want scroll gestures to be listened by scrolView and single tap gesture is listened by `UItableView`. 
**Also using this layout is against the HIG of Apple**

Comment: Refer [UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell touch detect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636844/uiscrollview-inside-uitableviewcell-touch-detect) link it shows touch detects

Comment: it is best you can add single tap gesture to the tableview in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scroll view is a subview of the table view, you can capture the gesture and send it to its parent view like this:

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but since I didn't really find a good answer I figured I'd offer one. This approach captures the tap events on both the UIScrollView (contained 'within' the table cell) AND tap events on the UITableView cells directly, and passes them along to the UITableViewDelegate. It also allows you to scroll your UIScrollView content without passing the scroll events along. Doesn't require any subclassing.

1. Within ViewDidLoad, instantiate a UITapGestureRecognizer on the UITableView

> ```
> // Capture taps on scrollView fields and pass along to tableView
> let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapIntercept:")
> tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
> ```

2. Create a callback function for the selector above

> ```
> // Get the location of the table cell beneath the scrollView and pass the event off to the tableView
> func tapIntercept(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) { 
>     let point = recognizer.locationInView(tableView)
>     if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {
>         tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
>     }  
> }
> ```