# indexPath.row not giving correct value in tableView custom cell iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I made custom `cell` with `scrollView`on right side of the `cell` and `imageView` on left side. Now when I click on `imageView` I get correct value for `indexPath.row`, but when I click on `scrollView indexPath.row` is returning value from last image that was clicked. Any suggestions how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *hlCellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc]
               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:hlCellID];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize =   CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0+i*100, 0, 100, 100)];
        label.text = @"HELLO";
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width+i*label.frame.size.width,scrolView.frame.size.height);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show the scrollView code that identifies the cell, please.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: I added code for setting scroll view in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: If you have a custom cell, make a custom class and connect your scrollview and imageview as a property! This will save you lots of trouble.

Comment: Please add your code where you receive the wrong value (i. e. your didSelect method). Your other code is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
```

Change above line with following.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

i hope this works for you..

Comment: Tag is value that is setted in storyboard so I can identify my custom cell and scrollView in it. indexPath.row is not constant value.

Comment: but please tell me, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to make EPG and I need Program Guide on right side that can slide left and right. I need to set all scrollViews in tableView to slide when I slide one of them, so I need indexPath.row of that cell in scrollViewDidScroll method, and I need to set rest of cells to make contentOffset same as that cell.

Comment: then you can get tag of scrollview with using indexPath.row and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I know that, but indexPath.row is not returning correct value of selected row when i click on scrollView inside cell, and when I click outside of scrollView it works correctly.

Comment: i think following link may helps you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636844/uiscrollview-inside-uitableviewcell-touch-detect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185446/horizontal-uiscrollview-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-ib-storyboard-no

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this doc reference: [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

Basically your event doesn't goes uphill the responder chain because scroll view captures it. I don't know what you are trying to achieve but having scrollview inside a scrollview(because tables are scrollviews by their nature) is bad idea and is really hard to achieve.

Comment: I am making EPG and I need picture of program on left side, and Program Guide on right side that can slide left and right. Table view itself can't achieve that.