# Custom UITableViewCell didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell class that I use to draw my UITableViewCell. Everything is drawn correctly however due to the elements I am putting into my UITableViewCell I have been having problems with selecting the cell.

This is the method I use to draw the UITableViewCell which is my custom UITableViewCell

```
- (void)drawCell
{
    nameString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameString.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    nameString.frame = CGRectMake(15.0, 0.5, 70.0, 40.0);
    nameString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

    lastNameString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    lastNameString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lastNameString.frame = CGRectMake(105.0, 0.5, 95.0, 40.0);
    lastNameString.text = [itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"LastName"];

    addressString = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    addressString.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressString.frame = CGRectMake(220.0, 10.5, addressString.frame.size.width, 50.0);
    addressString.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ISN %@: %@",[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"AddNumber"] ,[itemsDictionary objectForKey:@"AddString"]];
    [addressString sizeToFit];

// scrollcell has a dynamic scrollwidth depending on the sddressString but has a framesize of a normal UITableViewCell
    scrollCell = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    scrollCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ScreenWidth, 45.0);
    [scrollCell setContentSize:(CGSizeMake((220.0 + addressString.frame.size.width)+15, 45.0))];

    [scrollCell addSubview:nameString];
    [scrollCell addSubview:lastNameString];
    [scrollCell addSubview:addressString];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:scrollCell];
}
```

As you can see I am adding a UIScrollView that covers the entire cell which I think is preventing the UITableViewCell delegate selection method.

How can I get the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath to work?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I feel like naming your labels with a "String" suffix is very misleading.  It makes the code less understandable.  Just a suggestion though!

Comment: Yea I agree now that you bring it up... I didnt even think about which is bad of me!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following?

```
@implementation ViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and set the delegate to self?

```
self.tableview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yea I have done this, sorry I should have refrenced the fact.

Answer (score 0):

A UIScrollView in a cell is always going to be a problem because it intercepts events. If you can, rely on the fact that the table view scrolls and make the cell as large as it needs to be to display the content.

If you must have the scroll view there you will probably have to add a view over the top of the cell, add your own gesture recognisers, and choose which events will be sent to the table view and which to the scrollview.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6641789/189804) also - you can send touchesBegan/Moved/Ended to nextResponder also.

Comment: Okay, this was something I was going to investigate... but I thought there might be a different solution.. I think I can figure this out going to start some research.

Answer (score 0):

One of the other two answers is probably the right path but just in case if you are using storyboard segue those will get before didSelectRowAtIndexPath so code you have in there may be irrelevant depending on the segue and what happens.