# Table view cell (containing horizontal scroll view) not clickable

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using table view cells which contain a horizontal scroll view. Unfortunately, clicking on them doesn't work, the `didSelectRowAt` method is not called.

Setting `userInteractionEnabled` on the scroll view to `false` (which I don't want) fixes it.

Comment: You can take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24284116/3844242).

Comment: @StefanStefanov thanks, the answer below it solved it for me